# O eclipse esta retornando esse erro "R can not be resolved to the variable"

Tags: android, eclipse

Eu estava programando normalmente até que eu limpar meu projeto para remover os avisos, o eclipse limpou com sucesso, mas me exibe esse erro

> R can not be resolved to the variable

Em todos os códigos java eu tenho no meu projeto.

O que eu faço?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Confundiu o site do Stackoverflow com o Stackoverflow em Português amigo? Só traduzir.

Comment: Normalmente isso é resolvido com Project->Clean. Verifique antes se não tem nenhum arquivo xml por gravar.

Comment: tenho tudo gravado, não tem erro nenhum, eu simplesmente dei um clean e todos estes javas ficaram com este erro, não sei porquê